# How to hide Action bar and Tab Layout when video player is in full screen mode inside a tab?

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-video-player

I have a ViewPager which is in a fragment , this fragment has an actionBar and a tabLayout , inside on of its tab I have a videoPlayer , when I fullScreen the video , the action bar and tab layout dont get hidden , How can I get full screen video with action bar and tab layout hidden ?

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                         
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="rtl">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

<fragment
 android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerFragment"
 android:layout_width="280dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start"

 tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="7dp">

<include
 layout="@layout/giraffe_player"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="210dp" />


 <com.jude.easyrecyclerview.EasyRecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_empty="@layout/view_empty"
 app:layout_progress="@layout/view_progress"
 app:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
 android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

when the video player is on full screen you can set

```
findViewById(R.id.tab_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

when exit full screen set

```
findViewById(R.id.tab_layout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: What about action bar